# Trouble with obtaining url from html in python

Tags: python, html, selenium

Having trouble extracting the url from the background picture on this website. This picture refreshes every 5 minutes, changing the url so as far as I am aware I am forced to use this website, refresh every 5 minutes and grab this url. Ultimately, I am trying to grab this image every 5 minutes to create a video. I am able to navigate to the Div that I need, but when I am trying to split the string, I get errors about it not being a string. when is use `print(type(divreq))` I get a `bs4.element.Tag`.

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
url = "https://camera.deckchair.com/emporium-hotel-brisbane-australia"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
divreq = soup.find('div',class_='image')
print(divreq)
```

my output is:

```
<div _ngcontent-ptg-1="" class="image" style='background-image: url("//api.deckchair.com/v1/viewer/image/610a5f61a95c310001bf67ba?width=1280&amp;height=720&amp;resizeMode=fill&amp;gravity=Auto&amp;quality=90&amp;panelMode=false&amp;format=jpg"); background-position: 50% 50%;'> </div>
```

The information I am trying to get is:

```
api.deckchair.com/v1/viewer/image/610a5f61a95c310001bf67ba
```

with the `610a5f61a95c310001bf67ba` changing every 5 mintues.

Answer (score 1):

using selenium, you can use `get_attribute`

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
attr_value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.image").get_attribute('style')
print(attr_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will search string between image/ and ?

```
import re
x = re.search(r'(?<=image/).+(?=\?)', divreq).group()
print(x)
```